# How to setup Git with Mediawiki?

Tags: mysql, git, mediawiki

I recently made my own personal MediaWiki and I would like it to be available on different computers. I set it up with XAMPP, so currently, what I did was make two repositories:

- one for xampp\htdocs\(my-wiki)
- one for xampp\mysql\data\(my-sql-folder)

Then I cloned those repositories to the same folders on another computer. However, when I go to localhost(my-wiki) on that computer, I get the error "Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties. (Cannot access the database)."

Whenever I make changes to the Wiki, xampp\htdocs(my-wiki) does not change at all, while xampp\mysql\data(my-sql-folder) frequently shows edits. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: After looking at the internal error data, it appears that none of the tables in the wiki exist anymore (Table xxx doesn't exist in engine). I'm unsure of why this would be!

Comment: Another thing I tried: going into phpMyAdmin and adding the same user account that I had on the other computer. I also gave permission to "Any" user on any host name with no passwords. Then MediaWiki gives the error:MediaWiki internal error.

Exception caught inside exception handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that change when you use a wiki: the uploads directory and the database, so for some some sort of decentralized wiki you need to replicate those. Uploads are simple (you could use git, or some shared central storage like NFS, or some decentralized file store - Wikipedia for example uses Swift). As for the database, there are a few experimental tools to use git as a storage engine (e.g. [git-mediawiki](https://github.com/Git-Mediawiki/Git-Mediawiki/wiki/User-manual)), but nothing I would rely on. If your computers run all the time, you can use database replication, but that's not a beginner-level setup. In practice you'll probably be best off just using [database dumps](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki). Or buy a server on the internet (a decent VPS is pretty cheap these days) and use that as the wiki's DB backend so you can reach it from all your machines. (Or I guess you can just put your whole wiki on the internet at that point.)

Comment: I may go ahead and try putting it on a server on the Internet, just to help myself learn. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was missing the files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1 from the xampp/mysql/data folder. This, however, makes my Git setup even more annoying. If anybody has any suggestions for a better way to setup my Wiki and make it available across different computers, it'd be much appreciated! Thanks